# How to get dedicated Apache Kafka MirrorMaker 2.0 Rest API exposed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to reach a dedicated MirrorMaker 2.0 cluster to see the status of connectors/tasks etc. On this [README in their git](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/README.md) Apache kafka people claims that when used with dedicated.mode.enable.internal.rest=true MirrorMaker nodes are starting with an internal listener port to communicate with each other.

My question is; Is there a way to advertise this port to outside so I can send curl requests to the dedicated MirrorMaker nodes as we do in general like curl http://localhost:8083/connectors to see the connectors running etc?

I have already tried multiple solutions I've found online they simply do not work. It seems to me this is impossible when you start mirrormaker 2.0 with ./bin/connect-mirror-maker. I know this is possible, If I add every single required connector manually to an existing Kafka Connect cluster, but thats not what I am looking for.

I am also curious if there is a way to add the dedicated MirrorMaker cluster connectors into a already running kafka connect cluster.

This is important because we would like to get curl responses to check tasks status for MirrorMaker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `connect-distributed` like normal, have its REST API available, then configure and monitor MM2 without using its dedicated scripts. Similarly, this is how you'd add to other existing Connect cluster.

Ideally, you should monitor from JMX, instead, where you get count of the running tasks, not use curl. Or, add Jolokia or Prometheus JMX Exporter to run their own http server, then curl that, and grep for the tasks metric

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we are monitoring dedicated mm2 with jmx agent of prometheus. But since no rest api is available we cannot restart or pause individual tasks, we can only see the count etc.